# sqlite syntax for deleting when a condition applies

Tags: sqlite

I want to delete from a table the shortest entries when there are more than 100 rows.

I think that I need to perform the following:

Order by the length of the desired column and delete the first (or last) X entries over the limit of 100 rows.

the first part would be something like:

```
select rowid, length(column_name) as length from table order by length;
```

but how to delete the after the 100th?

Answer (score 0):

I conjured up this technique, not sure it is optimal:

```
WITH cte AS 
  (SELECT rowid, length(column) AS length FROM table order by length desc limit 100)  
DELETE FROM table WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT rowid FROM cte);
```

Comment: It's fine. Just a simplification: `WITH cte AS (SELECT rowid FROM tablename ORDER BY LENGTH(column_name) DESC LIMIT 100) DELETE FROM tablename WHERE rowid NOT IN cte;`